# synchronize max value while one thread add items and one thread removes items

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I'm implementing a program with ArrayList with Objects called Bicycle in it.

I maintain a variable to save the max Bicycle (measured by its id) and a variable to save the max Bicycle index in the array.

I have implented 2 functions - **addBicycle** and **removeMax** and they are *synchornized*.

I'm worried about what might happen when one thread is in addBicycle and other thread is in removeMax - one might add new bicycle which will be the maximum and the second thread will remove accidently older value which is no longer a maximum.

Is there a way to prevent it? a way to forbid that one thread will be at the add function and the other at the remove function, at the same time?
Thanks

edit: code -

```
public BicycleDataStructure() {
    list = new ArrayList<T>();
    maxBicycle = null;
    maxBicycleIndex = 0;
}


public synchronized void addBicycle(T bToAdd) {

    if (list.size() == 0) {
        list.add(bToAdd);
        maxBicycle = bToAdd;
        maxBicycleIndex = 0;

    } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {


                //checks to add in the right position in the list


                list.add(i, bToAdd); }


    }


}

public synchronized Bicycle removeMaxBicycle() {
    if (list.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    } 

    list.remove(maxBicycleIndex);

    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        maxBicycle = collection.get(maxBicycleIndex- 1);
        maxBicycleIndex-= 1;

    } 


}
```

Comment: "when one thread is in addBicycle and other thread is in removeMax" can't happen if they are synchronized on the same monitor.

Comment: @AndyTurner why? if a function is synchronized it means that 2 threads can't be at the same time inside of that function, but these are 2 different functions

Comment: If they are synchronized methods on the same instance, only one thread can call any of the methods at a time.

Comment: As @AndyTurner says, the big question here is which lock is used to synchronize those 2 methods, could you show your code? (I would assume the same as Andy that you're using the object's intrinsic lock, I'd simply prefer a confirmation)

Comment: @asettouf I added the relevant code

Comment: Technically if your `list` instance is not accessed directly, but **only** from your `BicycleDataStructure`, you won't get any issue. (since `list` is package protected, it is not guaranteed). Now a possibly better way to handle this would be to use directly a synchronized list: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-

Comment: @asettouf no, using a synchronized list wouldn't make things safe, since the OP has check-then-act operations, that wouldn't be atomic, and also acts on separate fields (maxBicycle, maxBicycleIndex).

Comment: @JBNizet Fair point there, I was just pointing out a possible improvement, though indeed refactoring would be involved

Comment: @JBNizet what should I do to make it safe?

Comment: @user7366106 nothing. As already explained in comments above, your code is safe as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using synchronized method on same object lock so it is safe due to below reason

> It is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the
>   same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized
>   method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized
>   methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first
>   thread is done with the object.
>
> Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes
>   a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a
>   synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes
>   to the state of the object are visible to all threads.

Answer (score -1):

With your current implementation, it will not work as you expect. The `synchronized` keyword just prevent that two threads cannot access that block of code at the same time. However what you've got is two different methods and the situation you described might happen.

When you need to synchronize two methods, consider using semaphore:

```
private static final int MAX_AVAILABLE = 1;
private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_AVAILABLE, true);

public Bicycle removeMaxBicycle(){
   semaphore.acquire();
   //do your critical stuff
   semaphore.release();
}

public void addBicycle(T bToAdd) {
   semaphore.acquire();
   //do your critical stuff
   semaphore.release();
}
```

If you have any doubt in how to use Semaphore in Java, checkout this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: This is plain wrong. Both methods use the same lock (this), and thus if one thread executes one method, no other thread can execute the other.